# iTextSharp - The PDF does not display foreign characters

Tags: winforms, pdf

I have Form 3, where the Textbox and label are written with the characters "ěščřžýáíé" and that when creating a PDF in iTextSharp (finished PDF file)
does not display the desired characters "ěščřžýáíé", the space is empty. If it is listed in English, it works perfectly.
Please, how to edit the code to be able to "read" both Label and Textbox correctly.
I have now changed the label to Textbox, but I do not know how to do it to display the characters "ěščřžýáíé" and create PDF including characters ..

cod sample:

```
using (SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog() { Filter = "PDF file|*.pdf", ValidateNames = true })
            {
                if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    iTextSharp.text.Document doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document (PageSize.A4.Rotate());
                    try
                    {   
                        PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(sfd.FileName, FileMode.Create));
                        doc.Open();
                        doc.Add(new iTextSharp.text.Paragraph(textBox4.Text));
                        doc.Add(new iTextSharp.text.Paragraph(cisloTextBox.Text));
                        doc.Add(new iTextSharp.text.Paragraph(textBox5.Text));
                        doc.Add(new iTextSharp.text.Paragraph(prijmeniComboBox.Text));
                        doc.Add(new iTextSharp.text.Paragraph(textBox6.Text));
                        doc.Add(new iTextSharp.text.Paragraph(zaznamTextBox.Text));
                        doc.Add(new iTextSharp.text.Paragraph(textBox7.Text));
                        doc.Add(new iTextSharp.text.Paragraph(poznamkaTextBox.Text));
                        doc.Add(new iTextSharp.text.Paragraph(textBox10.Text));
                        doc.Add(new iTextSharp.text.Paragraph(telefonTextBox.Text));
                        doc.Add(new iTextSharp.text.Paragraph(textBox9.Text));
                        doc.Add(new iTextSharp.text.Paragraph(emailTextBox.Text));
                        doc.Add(new iTextSharp.text.Paragraph(textBox8.Text));
                        doc.Add(new iTextSharp.text.Paragraph(oznameniComboBox.Text));
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        doc.Close();
                    }

                }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a font that knows all the characters you need. Your code uses the default font which usually uses **WinAnsiEncoding** and, therefore, does not know those special characters.

Comment: check this out: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/81/iTextSharp-Working-with-Fonts